How to make a Stylus pen at home?
I was just wondering if it is possible to make a Stylus pen for myself from an ordinary pen.
If so , It would be wonderful.

Does How to Make a Pen Stylus: 10 Steps (with Pictures) - wikiHow answer your question?

Materials needed:

An ordinary pen (preferably with a removable tip)
A conductive material(e.g.,copper wire, aluminum foil, or conductive ink)
Electrical tape or glue
A small metal or plastic rod

Instructions:

Disassemble the pen and remove the tip.
Wrap the conductive material around the pen's tip or a small metal/plastic rod.
Secure the conductive material with electrical tape or glue.
Reassemble the pen.
Test the stylus on your device.

Good luck and have fun with your DIY project!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You might want to add something about how to avoid the conductive material scratching the device.
